# Generalize Axios requests into one function

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

This question is about code refactoring and axios requests.

In my code I have multiple calls with the same structure to the same url, so I want to create an auxiliar function to make all the requests and avoid code repetition.

Here is my code:

```
const axios = require("axios");

// Create an axios instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://${endPoint}`, // The endpoint is the base url
  timeout: 50000, // Timeout limit = 50 secs.
  headers: {
    // Base headers
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Subscription-Key": apiKey,
  },
});

// Here I have multiple repetitive API calls using Axios 

function firstQuery() {
   const urlPath = "/1/...";
   const data = { ... };

   return axiosInstance.post(urlPath, data)
      .then((res) => res)
      .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response) {
             /* 
               The request was made and the server responded with a status code
               that falls out of the range of 2xx
             */
             throw err.response;
          } else if (err.request) {
              // Client never received a response, or request never left
              throw err.request;
          } else {
              // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
              throw error.message;
          }
      });
}


function secondQuery() {
   const urlPath = "/2/..."; // different urlPath
   const data = { ... };

   return axiosInstance.get(urlPath, data) // Different method GET
      .then((res) => res) 
      .catch((err) => { //CODE REPETITION...
          if (err.response) {
             /* 
               The request was made and the server responded with a status code
               that falls out of the range of 2xx
             */
             throw err.response;
          } else if (err.request) {
              // Client never received a response, or request never left
              throw err.request;
          } else {
              // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
              throw error.message;
          }
      });
}
```

This is my first time using Axios so I don't know if this is a common scenario... Any ideas?
I would appreciate someone to help me.

I am looking for something like this:

```
 function makeAxiosRequest(method, urlPath, data) {
     return axiosInstance ...    // Make a general request
 }
```

Comment: I think best way to achive what you want is using interceptors, not current the answer: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: I have tested the answer and working fine... If I replace it with interceptors would I be also able to handle error responses from the server?

Comment: Of course you can. You can handle responses and requests from interceptors. Assume that you have an api that doesnt have http status codes. In this situation you cannot catch errors via axios cause there is no actually error. But, with interceptors you can configure axios to throw exception like there is an actual error. I mean if your json response has status with false(or something) but you dont want to handle it in then block(its very ugly), you can easily direct it to catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Your example function signature looks correct to me. Implementation would be something like this (might not be exact, please edit the answer or let me know if it doesn't work):

```
function makeAxiosRequest(method, urlPath, data) {
   return method(urlPath, data)
      .then((res) => res)
      .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response) {
             /* 
               The request was made and the server responded with a status code
               that falls out of the range of 2xx
             */
             throw err.response;
          } else if (err.request) {
              // Client never received a response, or request never left
              throw err.request;
          } else {
              // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
              throw error.message;
          }
      });
}
```

`firstQuery` and `secondQuery` could then look like this:

```
function firstQuery() {
    return makeAxiosRequest(axiosInstance.post, "/1/...", { ... });
}

function secondQuery() {
    return makeAxiosRequest(axiosInstance.get, "/2/...", { ... });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [method alias](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) so I suppose that making a simple axios request passing a configuration object will work.

> Requests can be made by passing the relevant config to axios. *Axios Documentation*

So, you have it easy. Just do this:

```
function makeAxiosRequest(method, urlPath, data) {
  /* Auxiliar function to make different axios requests to my endpoint */

  return axiosInstance({
    method,
    url: urlPath,
    data,
  })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        /* 
          The request was made and the server responded with a status code
          that falls out of the range of 2xx
        */
        throw err.response.data;
      } else if (err.request) {
        // Client never received a response, or request never left
        throw err.request;
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        throw new Error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
      }
    });
}
```

And use it like this:

```
function query() {
    ...
    return makeAxiosRequest("POST", urlPath, data);
}
```

Please, let me know if this doesn't work.